# Specific validation for specific action in CakePHP 2.3

Tags: php, cakephp

How I can do that?

In specific action, i want to validate just 1 field. In another, 3 fields, etc.
But isn't just in create/update, for example:

I have a **search form**, with some filters, and need validate if user filled all fields (not in javascript).

---

## Details

**CakePHP:** 2.3
**MySQL:** 5.1
**Apache:** 2.2
**PHP:** 5.3.9

Comment: please be more specific and describe what you've tried, what you want to happen, what data you have...etc etc etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to run `Model->validates()` manually with an array of fields you want validated. Then run ->save() without validation check.

```
$this->ModelName->set($this->request->data);
if ($this->ModelName->validates(array('fieldList' => array('email', 'password')))) {
      $this->ModelName->save($this->request->data, false); //false = no validation checking
}
```

ref: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](https://gist.github.com/ADmad/4038473) a fancy solution for switching validation rules based on actions.

Comment: Excellent! But for my needs, the other solution is better. Anyway, thanks @ADmad